# Filtering a Table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, will-paginate

I am working with will_paginate to create a sortable and searchable table. I have got everything to work correctly with the exception of the search box (filter). Right now when I select a different query (other than "title") and search for something, it only searches for title querys. Can anyone help point out where I am going wrong?

Thank you!

index controller:

```
filter = case params['sform']
  when "filter=Title" then "title"
  when "filter=Size" then "size"
  when "filter=Film Type" then "film_type"
  when "filter=Premiere" then "premiere"
  when "filter=Preferred Date" then "preferred_date"
  when "filter=Actual Date" then "actual_date"
end


sort = case params['sort']
       when "title"  then "title"
       when "premiere"   then "premiere"
       when "film_type" then "film_type"
    when "preferred_date" then "preferred_date"
    when "actual_date" then "actual_date"
    when "created_at" then "created_at"
    when "updated_at" then "updated_at"
       when "size" then "size"
       when "title_reverse"  then "title DESC"
       when "premiere_reverse"   then "premiere DESC"
       when "film_type_reverse" then "film_type DESC"
    when "preferred_date_reverse" then "preferred_date DESC"
    when "actual_date_reverse" then "actual_date DESC"
    when "created_at_reverse" then "created_at DESC"
    when "updated_at_reverse" then "updated_at DESC"
       when "size_reverse" then "size DESC"

       end

conditions = ["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] unless params[:query].nil?

@total = Video.count(:conditions => conditions)
 @videos = Video.paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 100, :order => sort, :conditions => conditions
if request.xml_http_request?
  render :partial => "video_list", :layout => false
end
```

Index view:

```
<form name="sform" action="" style="display:inline;">
<br>
<label for="item_name">Search by  <%= select_tag "filter", "<option>Title</option>,<option>Size</option>,<option>Film Type</option>,<option>Premiere</option>,<option>Preferred Date</option>,<option>Actual Date</option>" %>: </label>
<%= text_field_tag(:query, params['query'], :size => 10, :id => 'query') %>

</form>

<%= image_tag("spinner.gif",
              :align => "absmiddle",
              :border => 0,
              :id => "spinner",
              :style =>"display: none;" ) %>
</p>

<%= observe_form 'sform',  :frequency => 1,
         :update => 'table',
         :before => "$('#spinner').show()",
         :success => "$('#spinner').hide()",
         :url => {:action => 'list'},
         :with =>  'sform'  %>


<div id="table">
<%= render :partial => "video_list" %>
</div>
```

Still cannot figure out how to make it search by the filter type. Any more suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In the last part there:

```
conditions = ["title LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%"] unless params[:query].nil?
```

The conditions you're passing explicitly are searching by title.  Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Try setting your values to a variable as well.

values = { :filter = filter }

condition = ":filter LIKE ?", params[:query]

Comment: Hmm I am not sure if I know what you mean by set my values. I got this code from another website... I am not so good with ruby yet... I can get around and understand most of it but this is confusing me. If the filter is size then I want to query based on size and so on.